# iCal Not Recognized By Google

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I've created an iCal which I'm trying to use in Google Calendar, but no events are being displayed. The feed is at [here](http://feed2ical.appspot.com/convert?url=https%3A%2F%2Fviews.scraperwiki.com%2Frun%2Frss_2%2F%3Fscraper%3Ddays_of_the_year%26table%3Devents%26title%3Dname%26link%3Dlink%26desc%3Dname%26date%3Ddate%26order%3Ddate%26limit%3D100). Each event looks like the following, and two iCal validators are telling me it's a valid file. Does google need an extra field for each entry?

Comment: looking at your link on feed2ical it is empty, could be the issue why google calendar cannot find any event?

Comment: Updated, looks like something went wrong when I pasted it in.

Comment: have you tried removing the empty line between events. per rfc5545 this is not valid and might be the cause for google calendar not to take your feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my own iCal dumper at https://views.scraperwiki.com/run/days_of_the_year_1/ , which builds the source piece by piece. It won't work when I subscribe online via Google calendar, but if I save, then import the source the events are added. I guess there must be an out of place character in feed2ical's ouput.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time, but I finally noticed that my old feed2ical script was busted in various ways.  It should be fixed now and I put the source on github as well.  Man I really didn't know python when I wrote that :)  It's still pretty crappy code, but it validates now and works in Google Calendar, Apple's iCal, and Microsoft Outlook.

http://feed2ical.appspot.com, https://github.com/dsanvita/feed2ical